# Parse a line using split method in Java

Tags: java, split

```
request = GET /solr1/select?q=reqRelDate_l%3A%5B1321516800000+TO+1321775940000%5D+AND+requestStatus_s%3ASUB29&wt=javabin&version=1 HTTP/1.1
```

or

```
request = GET /solr1/select?q=reqRelDate_l%3A%5B1321516800000+TO+1321775940000%5D+AND+requestStatus_s%3ASUB29&wt=javabin&version=1 HTTP/1.1
```

And I want to get all the data of ***&fq=*** So in the first case &fq= contains

```
doctype_s%3Acom.host.ems.qsrr.SurveyInstance
fq=%21survey_id_l%3A%2829%29
```

So I want filter should contain the value starting from first ***&fq=***   meaning that filter should contain the below value for the first case. And request can have many ***&fq=*** so I want filter to have value starting from ***&fq=***

```
doctype_s%3Acom.host.ems.qsrr.SurveyInstance&fq=%21survey_id_l%3A%2829%29
```

So if I do by this way-- then I get only first value of &fq= not other value.. So what's the best way to get all the value starting from first &fq= and replacing these thing `&wt=javabin&version=1 HTTP/1.1`

```
filter = request.split("&fq=")[1];
```

I need to parse the above request string so that I can get the value of &fq= in the filter variable..

Comment: so do you want the entire contents of the string after the first &fq= or only values of &fq= ?

Comment: I need specifically entire contents of string after first &fq= but not this `&wt=javabin&version=1 HTTP/1.1` as request also contains that thing also... Question is clear enough I need to parse the above line so that I can get the value of &fq= in filter variable..

Comment: it apparently isn't clear enough if people are asking you to clarify. I am reading your response as you want all the values of the &fq paramters? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head I guess you could do something like this:

```
String[] params = request.split("&");
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    if (params[i].startsWith("fq")) {
        String[] fqsplit = params[i].split("=");
        if (fqsplit.length > 1) {
            values.add(fqsplit[1]);
        }
    }
 }
```

Now you will have a List with all the values of the fq parameters.

Sure I could come up with something more clever.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always another &VAR following &fq=, you can do:

`String fq_stuff = filter.split("&")[0];`

Answer (score 0):

If it is truly the first instance of fq, why not be simple??  I really think all these splits and regexs are overkill sometimes.

```
int firstFQ = request.indexOf("&fq");
if (firstFQ < 0)
   throw new SomeException();
int nextAmp = request.indexOf("&", firstFQ+1);
if (nextAmp < 0)
   throw new SomeException();
return request.subString(firstFQ+3, nextAmp);  // I may have an off by 1 error here
```

You can clean this up by making "&fq" a nice constant or an arg passed in.